# How to display units for opencart?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.3

Tell me how to display units for opencart 2.3. When the goods were measured in grams, I simply added the "gr" after the weight was displayed. And now I need to display "liters" as well, as now this crutch has outlived itself. How to address the variable that is responsible for the output of units (gr, kg, l) ??

This is how I used to get weight

```
<?php if($product['weight']>0) { ?>
    <div class="weight">
        <?php echo $product['weight']; ?>гр.
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

In the “popular” module and in the categories and in the product’s card itself, I derive the weight using the code above. But this code does not display the units (grams, kilograms, tons) that I choose in the admin panel when creating the product.

Everything that is highlighted with red colour needs to be displayed automatically from the admin panel.

[image]

Comment: which page you want?

Comment: @Mujahid Bhoraniya Card Product

Comment: please upload with a proper screenshot because we will understand easily.

Comment: @Mujahid Bhoraniya Changed the question, added a picture, please see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example weight php code, I assume you mean how to display the weight with unit in the product page.
The code I am attaching below will help you do that easily.

Open file:

> *catalog/**model**/catalog/product.php*

Find line:

```
public function getProduct($product_id) {
```

Before the line mentioned above **add the following code**:

```
public function getProductWeightWithUnit($product_id) {
    $product_info = $this->getProduct($product_id);

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT unit FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description` WHERE 
    weight_class_id='".$product_info['weight_class_id']."'");

    if ($query->num_rows) {
        return number_format($product_info['weight'],2) . " " . $query->row['unit'];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Save changes and close the file.

Now, open file:

> *catalog/**controller**/product/product.php*

Find line:

```
if ($product_info['minimum']) {
```

Before the line mentioned above **add the following code**:

```
if ($product_info['weight']) {
     $data['weight'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductWeightWithUnit($this->request->get['product_id']);
} else {
     $data['weight'] = false;
}
```

Now, the backend code is ready. Based on the theme that you use, you need to edit the correct *product.tpl* file from your theme. For example if you use the default theme, then the file to edit is the following:

> catalog/view/theme/**default**/template/product/product.tpl

Find the line:

```
<li><?php echo $text_stock; ?> <?php echo $stock; ?></li>
```

and add the following code after:

```
<li><?php echo $weight; ?></li>
```

The above example will show the weight like this:
[image: Example of the above code]

Comment: Thanks, but something is not working. I changed the question, added a picture, see.

Comment: That's the category page. You can copy my backend code and use it for the category.php and the category.tpl files in your template.

Comment: Thanks! Earned! Hard to clear cache) Could you tell me please now, how to do the same for the “Featured Products” module?

Comment: Similar code. Backend: catalog/controller/extension/module/featured.php
 and front end: catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/module/featured.tpl

Comment: Please tell me where to insert it? No matter how I insert it, constantly errors